# PHP Drupal file_get_contents() failed to open stream : permission denied

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have deployed `Drupal 7.33` to `IIS 7.5.` The installation went great, everything worked as advertised.

When I deployed a new theme, I've started getting the errors below:

> Warning: file_get_contents(sites/all/modules/tabvn/widget/widget.info): failed to open stream: Permission denied in drupal_parse_info_file() (line 7286 of C:\Sites\drupal-7.32\includes\common.inc).

I can honestly say that this is `NOT a permissions problem as I have granted "ALL" permissions to Everyone`.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally figured out the problem, after wasting 5 hours of my life.

sites/all/modules/tabvn/widget/widget.info had the attribute "Encrypted"  (Attribute:AE)

Apparently this caused an "access denied" error.